# Azure Kubernetes Service- Get kubeconfig for non-admin AD app identity

Tags: node.js, azure-aks, azure-container-service

As per my understanding, Azure Kubernetes Service(AKS) allows getting credentials for admin and user identities. Can the user identity be an AD app or a managed identity?

I'm writing .Net code. Can you provide some sample where we can get the user credentials from AKS cluster by using AD app credentials, assuming I have already done AD integration with my AKS cluster and have already assigned the appropriate role binding for my AD app?

The security section here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managedclusters/getaccessprofile needs implicit flow. How does implicit flow work for AD app credentials?

Comment: Can you share you rolebinding? The SP ID should be available as the userID when setting the role binding

Comment: I can use the SP ID in role binding. But how to retrieve access profile? The security section here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managedclusters/getaccessprofile needs implicit flow. How does implicit flow work for AD app credentials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow) to get access token.

You'll need the [Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/control-kubeconfig-access) built-in role to access an Azure AD enabled cluster.

Get the user credentials to access the cluster:

```
az aks get-credentials --resource-group myResourceGroup --name MyManagedCluster
```

Or use [List Cluster User Credentials API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managedclusters/listclusterusercredentials).

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/{resourceName}/listClusterUserCredential?api-version=2020-04-01
```

Because [Get Access Profile API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managedclusters/getaccessprofile) **will be deprecated in the futhure**.

Comment: The implicit grant flow needs to happen through browser, but I am looking for a way to get credentials not based on a user login, but based on AD app credentials.

Comment: You can use [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) which do not need users login.